# How to combine different representations of the same object

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I have a set of 1000+ BW images, each containing several blobs. Each blob is present in a number of images, ideally in the same position (see pic below), with a different shape. I wrote a file listing the properties of the blobs (`x_center`, `y_center`, `number_of_pixels`, `width`, `height`), where `width` and `height` are respectively the x and y coordinate of the rectangle containing the considered blob.

For each blob, I want to combine the different shapes recorded in different images, assigning intensity = 1 to the pixels composing the blob in more than half of the images, and 0 otherwise.

I am now sketching the algorithm to combine the blobs, that I will write in Matlab or Python. This is what I would do for each of the elements of the list:

1. Check if there is any other element whose center is contained in the rectangle built around the considered one.
2. If yes, check if the centres of the two shapes are close enough.
3. If yes, check if the number of pixels composing the two shapes are comparable.
4. If yes, flag the line of the text file relative to the considered shape.

What do you think about this approach? And do you have any suggestion on how to combine the shapes relative to the same blob (marked with the same flag)? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What is an "element"?  Is it just a blob?

Comment: By "element" I denoted each of the lines composing the text file with info on the different blobs.

Comment: And what do you mean with "combine the shapes relative to the same blob"? If I understand you correctly you just want to look at the "blobs" so if you have two similar "blobs" (defined by some criteria) you want them to be flagged (marked in any way). But what do you mean with combine shapes? do you just want to add them so all used pixels are shown, should a pixel present in both be differently coded than one present only in one "blob"?

Comment: @TheMinion--> you're correct about the flagging, and regarding the shape combination, for a set of similar blobs I want to give value 1 to the pixels which are present in more than half of the blobs, and 0 otherwise

Comment: I'm mostly worried about the technical details, like: which data should I store in memory? Should I save images at a certain point?

Comment: It seems to me you don't need such a complicated algorithm. Just add the intensities of every pixel of all BW images together in one big table, create a new image, set the intensity per pixel to 0 if the total intensity in the table <= N/2, set the intensity per pixel to 1 if the toal intensity in the table > N/2 and then, if necessary, try to find your blob in this combined image.